# How to temporarily hide armature for other mesh?

Tags: armature

I'm trying to make a fight animation between this two.
[image]

But I'm having hard time positioning their body because the armature of the other one is being mixed to the armature of the other.

How do I hide the armature of the other one temporarily so I can position the other one properly?

I don't want to completely hide the mesh, only its armature, so I can see them both while working with only the armature of one guy being shown.

[.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y_lzZFk8lkTkT4OUpZmOAeRxmOkkGMnI) file.

Comment: you could hide it or put it on another layer?

Comment: @moonboots I don't want to completely hide the mesh, only its armature, so I can see them both while working with only one armature.

Comment: yes I meant switch your armature to object mode and hide it or put it on another layer, then bring it back when you have finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding the top object will only hide the skeleton, not the mesh.
If this is what you want to accomplish, Just click the hide button and you should be good!

[image]

[image]